# pandas - get difference to previous n-th rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Assume I have the following data frame in pandas, with accumulated values over time for all ids:

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.1999 | 2 |
| 2 | 01.01.1999 | 3 |
| 3 | 01.01.1999 | 5 |
| 1 | 03.01.1999 | 5 |
| 2 | 03.01.1999 | 8 |
| 3 | 03.01.1999 | 7 |

And I want to have the following, the difference for each id to the previous date:

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.1999 | 2 |
| 2 | 01.01.1999 | 3 |
| 3 | 01.01.1999 | 5 |
| 1 | 03.01.1999 | 3 |
| 2 | 03.01.1999 | 5 |
| 3 | 03.01.1999 | 2 |

This is basically the difference. I can only apply something like this:

`df["values"].diff().fillna(0)`

But this would not include the date column. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to groupby and `diff`

```py
df['value'] = df.groupby('id')['value'].diff().fillna(df['value'])
```

```
print(df)

   id        date  value
0   1  01.01.1999    2.0
1   2  01.01.1999    3.0
2   3  01.01.1999    5.0
3   1  03.01.1999    3.0
4   2  03.01.1999    5.0
5   3  03.01.1999    2.0
```